# Animated visibility of an object in render mode is different on rendered image

Tags: rendering

I was following a tutorial and everything was perfect until I saw the final render animation. 
The render view shows what I want

[image]

But then when I render the file the letters don't disappear.

[image]

I have no idea what the issue is. Any help?

This is the link for the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ect1165odmlwtnu/Firma.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

From your images it appears that you have keyframed the *visibility* of the writing - shown by the green around the ‘eye’ icons in the Outliner at the top-right of your images. However, that only controls the visibility in the 3D View window. In order to make the same effect on the rendered result you need to do the same on the *rederability* of each mesh - the camera icons in the Outliner window at the top-right (the rightmost icons).